# Unable to config pywebview caching directory

Tags: python, caching, webview, desktop-application, pywebview

I need to create a desktop app that access a webpage and also need to be able to control it's caching location (such as images of this webpage) for offline usage.

*Just like any browser already does?*
Yes, but I cannot use any browser like Firefox, Chrome, Chromium... Unless it's in the form of a DLL or something similar (the browser itself cannot be installed)

I already found how to delete cache and how to disable caching, just need to alter the caching directory.

take this code as example:

```
import webview
webview.create_window('Hello world', 'https://pywebview.flowrl.com/hello')
webview.start()
```

Let's suppose it downloads a image and stores it in cache.
I need to be able to open multiple instances of the application, each with it's separate caching directory.

Anyone knows how to change the caching directory? something like:

```
webview.cache.setDir("c://User/user-2")
```

I'm alright with the usage of other libs such ad flask or bottle (or any other really)

Also, the solution needs to work for both Widows and Ubuntu

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, There are third-party libraries you can use. Flask for instance works very well with pywebview. the webview.create_window method accepts an HTTP server(In this case flask). With flask you can then use the flask cache module to specify a directory to store the files
You can check the docs on flask caching to see other possibilities

https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/